# ST_Intersects Take time to fetch result

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have a Database with two tables, areas and properties, consisting of 1 million rows each. Now we are finding how many properties lie within a given area, we are using this query, but it takes time to fetch

```
SELECT count(*) FROM properties 
WHERE ST_Intersects(geom, '01030000000100000005000000456458C51B375240C173EFE1922333400E10CCD1E3375240335019FF3E23334011AAD4EC81385240E4BD6A65C227334068B3EA73B5375240FA449E245D2B3340456458C51B375240C173EFE192233340')
```

Is there a better approach we can follow?

Execution Plan

```
"Aggregate  (cost=38932.37..38932.38 rows=1 width=0)"
"  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on properties  (cost=463.41..38921.03 rows=4533 width=0)"
"        Recheck Cond: (geom && '01030000000100000005000000456458C51B375240C173EFE1922333400E10CCD1E3375240335019FF3E23334011AAD4EC81385240E4BD6A65C227334068B3EA73B5375240FA449E245D2B3340456458C51B375240C173EFE192233340'::geometry)"
"        Filter: _st_intersects(geom, '01030000000100000005000000456458C51B375240C173EFE1922333400E10CCD1E3375240335019FF3E23334011AAD4EC81385240E4BD6A65C227334068B3EA73B5375240FA449E245D2B3340456458C51B375240C173EFE192233340'::geometry)"
"              Index Cond: (geom && '01030000000100000005000000456458C51B375240C173EFE1922333400E10CCD1E3375240335019FF3E23334011AAD4EC81385240E4BD6A65C227334068B3EA73B5375240FA449E245D2B3340456458C51B375240C173EFE192233340'::geometry)"
```

Comment: Do you have a GiST index over `geom`?

Comment: Yes do have CREATE INDEX geom_properties_idx
  ON properties
  USING gist
  (geom);

Comment: And what is the execution plan for the given query?

Comment: Have added in Question

Comment: Any idea how we can improve this?

Comment: How long does it take and how many rows does it return? How complicated are the polygons? It is clear from your explain that the spatial index is being used to check the bounding boxes, the last line.

Answer (score 0):

The textbook answer is that you should first check for overlap of bounding boxes on each geometry.   I certainly found with queries on large numbers of geometries in both tables that:

```
select xxx  from   A, B
   where   A.geom && B.geom
                 AND
           ST_INTERSECTS(a.geom,b.geom);
```

...runs WAY faster - four orders of magnitude - than just using the ST_INTERSECTS alone.

Comment: Interesting. As [the documentation](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersects.html) states, _ST_Intersects_ "... automatically  includes a bounding box comparison that makes use of any spatial indexes that are available on the geometries." So in my eyes the _&&_ isn't necessary.